# Copy column from one table to another table with condition

Tags: sql-server, append

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Timesheet_update]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql2 nvarchar(max), @status nvarchar(1)

    SET @sql2 = 'insert into s21022020 (s21_stfno) select m_stfno from master where m_status<>'D''
    EXECUTE (@sql2)
END

EXECUTE Timesheet_update
```

Results in an error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
>   Invalid column name 'D'.

m_status column contain data =D

Comment: use two single quotes on each side of D `....from master /*?*/ where m_status<>''D''  ' `  on the right side of D there is a third single quote which denotes the end of @sql2

Comment: Why is this a "dynamic" statement? What purpose does `@status` serve, when it's never used?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you feel the need to make this a dynamic SQL - just write the statement directly inside the stored procedure - like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Timesheet_update]
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO s21022020 (s21_stfno) 
        SELECT m_stfno 
        FROM master 
        WHERE m_status <> 'D'
END
```